# Cant SELECT decimal Value

Tags: php, mysql, select, decimal

I know this question might sound simple to you, as if it case sensitive issue, However it is not. My problem is that when I try to grab a Decimal value(10,2)  it returns 0.00 but the rest of the rows it selected are fine. Here is my code:
This grabs the rows, most of them work and **ALL** of them are properly typed with Caps in the right places:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM invoice WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Couldn't execute query");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $DateCreated = $row['DateOfCreation'];
     $id = $row['id'];
    $Description = $row['Description'];
    $ProductCode = $row['ProductCode'];
    $VatRate = $row['VatRate'];
    $PriceExVat =  $row['PriceExVat'];
    $Status = $row['Status'];
}
```

This outputs the variable:

```
<input type="text" name="priceExVat" size="10" id="priceExVat" value="<? echo $PriceExVat; ?>"/>
```

Comment: `10,2`, euro-style decimal separation?

Comment: What is the SQL query you ran?  This code doesn't help.

Comment: Have you run the query manually in the MySQL monitor, make sure that 10,2 is stored in there?

Comment: Updated the code to show you my SQL Query.

Comment: When you say "Decimal value(10,2)", what do you actually mean? And what is the type of the table column that's storing the value?

Comment: The datatype of the column is "Decimal" and its Len or Length is "10,2"

Comment: Can anyone help? It seems like this question is being discarded!

Comment: Well first, SQL is not case sensitive. so `SELECT * FROM WHATEVER` is exactly the same as `select * from whatever`. Some DBs consider strings as case sensitive so something like `WHERE Column='TEST'` would not return the row where `column='test'`. Next, are you sure there is a value in the column? Chances are the value is just actually 0. Try inserting a value into the column, selecting it out and see if you get the same result (0.00) instead of the inserted value.

Comment: Checked and There is a value in there, which is not 0 or 0.00

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the PHP server has short tags disabled.  Try replacing

```
<? echo $PriceExVat; ?>
```

with

```
<?php echo $PriceExVat; ?>
```

Comment: I use short tags in all of my code. I will give this a shot however

Comment: In that case, we need more information - you should update your question to include the part of the PHP script that is actually supposed to be printing those lines - I don't see that code up there.